# the number of Young tableaux in general

Tags: combinatorics, young-tableaux

From the wiki page [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), we know the number of Young tableaux whose diagram is a 2-by-n rectangle given $2n$ distinct numbers is $C_n$. In general, given $m\times n$ distinct numbers, how many Young tableaux whose diagram is a $m\times n$  rectangle are there?

Also, what if these numbers can be repeated?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 12):

For the answer to your main question, you need to use the [hook-length formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook-length_formula#Dimension_of_a_representation).

[OEIS A060854](https://oeis.org/A060854) gives the result 
$$(mn)! \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{i!}{(m+i)!}  \textrm{ or equivalently } (mn)! \prod_{j=0}^{m-1} \frac{j!}{(n+j)!}  $$
and some more information.

Comment: This is the number of standard Young tableaux.

Comment: @Yuval: "Young tableaux" in the question really means "standard Young tableaux". To quote from the Wikipedia page linked to: "$C_n$ is the number of Young tableaux whose diagram is a 2-by-$n$ rectangle. In other words, it is the number ways the numbers $1, 2, \dots, 2n$ can be arranged in a 2-by-$n$ rectangle so that each row and each column is increasing. As such, the formula can be derived as a special case of the hook formula."

Comment: ...except that I've now edited the Wikipedia page so that it says *standard* tableaux, and has a link to the hook-length formula.

Answer (score 2):

It not quite clear what you mean by allowing repeated numbers, but what one usually considers in that case is so-called *semi-standard* Young tableaux, i.e., tableaux which are increasing (strict inequality) down each column, but only nondecreasing (equality allowed) along each row. The number of such arrangements on a given Young diagram, where the numbers $1,2,\dots,N$ are allowed, is counted as follows: define the "content" of box $(i,j)$ in the diagram to be $i-j$. Here's an illustration:

```
 0  1  2  3  4
-1  0  1  2
-2 -1  0
-3 -2
-4 -3
-5
```

Hook lengths are defined as for the usual hook-length formula for counting *standard* Young tableaux:

```
10  8  5  3  1
 8  6  3  1
 6  4  1
 4  2
 3  1
 1
```

To get the answer, take the product over all boxes of (($N$ plus the content of that box) divided by (the hook length for that box)).

(This is a special case of something called Stanley's hook-content formula.)