# Arrangements of $1,2,..,81$ in an $9 \times 9$ matrix such that each row and each column is increasing. How many possible $X$

Tags: combinations

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: Arrangements of $1,2,..,81$ in an $9 \times 9$ matrix such that each row and each column is increasing. How many possible $X$ ?

[image]

Comment: HINT: Try filling it from 1 to 81 and you will see that "almost" every number has exactly two options.

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23024/increasing-rows-and-columns may be helpful.

Comment: For a $2\times N$ rectangle, I get $1,2,5,14,...$, which might be Catalan numbers $\frac1{n+1}{2n\choose n}$ or the cumulative sum of powers of three.  I think it will be Catalan numbers because it is the number of ways of going from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ staying on or above the diagonal.

Comment: This equals the number of paths from $(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ to $(9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9)$ while ensuring the coordinates are always a (non-strictly) decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two obvious constraints are that all the other numbers in the rectangle from top left to $x$ are less than $x$ and all the numbers other than $x$ in the bottom right rectangle from $x$ to the corner are greater than $x$.

That gives a maximum and minimum value. Choose a value $x$ in this constrained range - can you fill in the rest of the numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You are counting standard Young tableaux (in the special case of square tableaux).  You want the [hook-length formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau); see also  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25867/the-number-of-young-tableaux-in-general).