# Counting the number of semistandard Young Tableaux with maximum entry $n.$ Reference/Formula request

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, integer-partitions, young-tableaux

> ***Question:*** If $k \leq n$ let $\lambda_k$ be a Young diagram with square $k \times k$ shape. I write  $\#_{\lambda_{k}^n}$ to count the
>   number of semistandard Young tableaux with shape $\lambda_k$ and
>   maximum entry $n$. For example if $n=4$ and $k=3$ then we draw 
>   $\lambda_{3}=
>          \begin{matrix}
>          \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
>          \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
>          \bullet & \bullet & \bullet \\
>         \end{matrix}$ and $\#_{\lambda_{3}^4}=20.$ Is there a known formula to compute $\#_{\lambda_{k}^n}$ ? "Googling" picks up the "content hook formula" - but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track! See if this answer helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25943/1242.

Comment: That answers it ! It is Stanley's [hook content formula](https://someproofsandstuff.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/hookcon.pdf).  Are there any "concrete formulas", in the sense of explicit closed products involving binomials if the diagram is known to be square ?

Comment: It's certainly possible to write it down in the form of a product, but I don't know if it simplifies to anything nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the hook content formula we have $$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{N+i-j}{k+i-j}$$ We can rewrite that as any of $$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{(N+i)^\underline{k}}{(k+i)^\underline{k}} = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{(N+i)!}{(N-k+i)!} \frac{i!}{(k+i)!} = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{N+i}{k} \binom{k+i}{k}^{-1}$$
The closest to a "closed product" is probably to write it as $$\frac{G(N+k+1)\;G(N-k+1)\;G(k+1)^2}{G(N+1)^2\;G(2k+1)}$$ where $G$ is the [Barnes G-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html) or superfactorial (although "supergamma" would perhaps be a better name given the offset).